# Insight in the diagonal method as explained by Girard

Tags: logic, set-theory, philosophy

I'm currently reading "The Blind Spot" by J.Y.Girard, and came across this passage about diagonalization:

[image]

[image]

Is this way of describing diagonal arguments in general legitimate? If not is there another formal way to describe every diagonal argument?

Comment: BTW I have tried presenting Russell's  "paradox" to people who are strongly non-mathematical by saying that it is illogical to assert the existence of a widget that dibbles all widgets that do not dibble themselves, and does not dibble any widget that dibbles itself.......  The ancient Greeks knew of the Barber Paradox: The barber that shaves all those and only those, who do not shave themselves.

Comment: You can see: Haim Gaifman, [Naming and Diagonalization: from Cantor to Godel to Kleene](http://www.columbia.edu/~hg17/naming-diag.pdf).

Comment: Also: Raymond Smullyan, [Diagonalization and Self-Reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=uH53QgAACAAJ), Oxford UP (1994)